# SQL | get query from 2 table with condition

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 tables, I want to display all user in list in my web, and show his last login details from table `tbl_login_details` but get the last login details for this user

1- diplay all my user from table - `tbl_user`

2- display LAST login for all user so the data of `tbl_login_details` must be ORDER then take THE LIMT

```
---------tbl_user-------
id    user_id   user_name 
1      5         mohammed
2      7          ahmed  

-------------tbl_login_details----------

  id       user_id    last_activity
  1         7          2016-5-2
  2         7          2017-4-2
  3         7          20-17-8-4
```

My Work is

```
$this->db->select('m.*,u.*'); 
$this->db->from('tbl_user m');
//$this->db->where("m.user_id", $id);
$this->db->join('tbl_login_details u ', 'u.user_id = m.user_id');
$where = 'm.user_id = u.user_id OR u.user_id = m.user_id  OR m.user_id=" "  ORDER  last_activity';
$where = $this->db->order_by("last_activity", "desc");
$this->db->where($where);
// $this->db->limit('1'); 
$this->db->group_by('m.user_id');// add group_by
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: i make it work , after multible try , i get this shit work  ... here is my code if any want want it , 
    $this->db->select('m.user_id, m.email , m.type, u.last_activity   ,u.id');
    $this->db->from('tbl_user m');
    $this->db->join('tbl_user_activity u ', 'u.user_id = m.user_id' ,'LEFT');
    $where = $this->db->select_max('u.last_activity');
   // $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->group_by('m.user_id');// add group_by
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

Answer (score 0):

use max aggregation to find the last activity:

```
select userid, max(last_activity)
from tbl_user a inner join tbl_login_details b on a.userid=b.userid
```

Comment: can u put this sql sentinse as my sentense to better understand to me

Answer (score 0):

are you try to get the last detail login from each user, If yes you can using ORDER DESC AND LIMIT 1

create query for display tbl_user first

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY id ASC
```

then you can create query for get last user login

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_login_details WHERE user_id = 7 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

you can using modal pop up for display detail login.

or are you try display like this ?

```
id    user_id   user_name  last_activity
1      5         mohammed   20-17-8-4
2      7          ahmed     20-17-8-4
```

Comment: can u make the quiry for me . couse i donot know how to make your quiry like mine

Comment: try this query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421762/sql-get-query-from-2-table-with-condition/52435980#52435980)

Comment: thanks , i wrote under my Q before 5 hourse , i succefly run the quiry

Answer (score 0):

May be you are searching for Following

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, (SELECT last_activity FROM tbl_login_details WHERE tbl_login_details.user_id = tbl_user.user_id  ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT 1) as last_activity FROM tbl_user
```

updated code. search for how to write this sub query in active record. or just use custom query like $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

Comment: it is get just one user - i want for each user the max details

Comment: i donto know how to move to codiener dataabse sturcure , i am try , but doesnot work

Comment: it is NOT WORK.

Answer (score 0):

help into CI max aggregation to find the last activity:

```
$query = $this->db->query("select userid, max(last_activity) from tbl_user a inner join tbl_login_details b on a.userid=b.userid");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple SQL code to fetch that. You can do it CodeIgniter's way: 
Implement this SQL into CodeIgniter.

```html
SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.user_name, tbl_login_details.user_id, tbl_login_details.last_activity FROM tbl_user, tbl_login_details WHERE tbl_user.user_id = tbl_login_details.user_id ORDER BY tbl_login_details.last_activity DESC
```

Comment: i make this , it is work , but does not give me the last login details for each , it s give me the first

Comment: $this->db->select('m.user_id,m.email, m.type,  u.last_activity '); 
$this->db->from('tbl_user m');
$this->db->join('tbl_login_details u ', 'u.user_id = m.user_id','LEFT');
         $this->db->order_by("u.last_activity", "desc");
          $this->db->group_by('m.user_id');// add group_by
 $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
SELECT u.id,u.user_id,u.user_name,MAX(l.last_activity) AS last_activity
FROM tbl_user u
LEFT JOIN tbl_login_details l ON(u.user_id=l.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

on codeigniter custom query builder

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT u.id,u.user_id,u.user_name,MAX(l.last_activity) AS last_activity FROM tbl_user u LEFT JOIN tbl_login_details l ON(u.user_id=l.user_id) GROUP BY u.user_id");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->id;
        echo $row->user_id;
        echo $row->user_name;
        echo $row->last_activity ;
}
```

Comment: i wore under my Q before 5 hourse ago . i made this quiry run succfly this , thanks